# Error "Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'" in a React component with a type parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to do this:

```
function SomeComponent<T>({ children }: PropsType) {
  const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState<T>({})
}
```

But I am getting:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMIQB2MSAHlgcQLJIgTZFIDKMKVcAvnABmUCCDgByKKgziAULJgBPMEjhlyg4AHN8UHsArqqtACrLVAXlyy4cNBU069MA+QBccCACMAVkgw2cMQw6o66+hQeABT2Gtoe3n4YAJRwFgB8cABuEMAAJrJ88jSQsHYUhPCh2uEuhhTG8BaByOgwAHRoUjykDTQwADzVThHkRv1mKulROIG2sWHOrh44fJhzQUghDjVLkXBRqRm4a4F8ycXUpfCC+OQYrmo7I3XkAAoiWflIUAMm03g0AALYAAGzyUnI-A8HwgYEIkyQqVm8wq8AA2gtdqNsMFhrVXABdNL0TjcKh-AHneSo8iVbIoUH4SykpgsKIbQ5pTIzDa0xY4vmbbZxF6uda2WznCWSzHPAkUXFbfF7ciEmUXQJSGC6KEcyVwIby1XjWjtWFfPI-BlMpAWHBZRnMvjpIU4YFgiFIchFA0DAD0KtGpo6Fu+UFdtguRQU5jgsPhiJJKLsIPBkI8rQw7SzMAAchArYUgA) is a playground with my current code.

I would like the `useState` value to be a deeply nested object (with leaf nodes as nested objects, strings, numbers, nulls, or arrays, etc., basically a JSON object). I tried this, but I got the same error:

```
function SomeComponent<T extends object>({ children }: PropsType) {
  const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState<T>({})
}
```

How do I type this correctly?

Comment: Why _is_ it a type parameter? Normally you'd do that if you wanted the inputs (props) or outputs (element) to use that generic type, but the state's an internal implementation detail.

Comment: How do you think `SomeComponent<never>` will behave?

Comment: The type to extend is `Record<any, any>` that should do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react'

type ConfigurationContextType = {
  configuration: Configuration
  setConfiguration: (config: object) => void
}

type Configuration = {
  darkMode?: boolean
}

export const ConfigurationContext =
  React.createContext<ConfigurationContextType>({
    configuration: {},
    setConfiguration: () => {},
  })

export function ConfigurationProvider({ children }: PropsType) {
  const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState<Configuration>({})

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      configuration,
      setConfiguration,
    }),
    [configuration, setConfiguration],
  )

  return (
    <ConfigurationContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ConfigurationContext.Provider>
  )
}

type PropsType = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}
```

You do not need to use generic.

I made a `Configuration` type and gave it to useState.